# Excel - Copy each row into new workbook but keep column names - Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I found this great Macro that copies each of my rows in my data frame separately into a new sheet, but keeps the first row with the column names as well:

```
 Sub abc_01()
 Dim WS As Worksheet, newWS As Worksheet
 Dim X As String
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Set WS = Sheets("Sheet1")
 On Error Resume Next
 X = InputBox("number of names 1,2,", , "9")
 For i = 1 To X
 Set newWS = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
 WS.Range("A1:G1").Copy Destination:=newWS.Range("A1")
 WS.Range(WS.Cells(i + 1, "A"), WS.Cells(i + 1, "G")).Copy
 newWS.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlValues
 Next i
 On Error GoTo 0
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

I tried now to copy it into a new workbook rather than a new sheet, but the new workbook stays empty when I run it. Also, I haven't saved the new workbooks yet as a new filename (ideally a specific cell value if possible?)

```
 Sub abc_02()
 Dim thisWB  As String
 Dim newWB As String
 thisWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name
 Dim X As String
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Set WS = Sheets("Sheet1")
 On Error Resume Next
 X = InputBox("number of names 1,2,", , "9")
 For i = 1 To X
 Workbooks.Add
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs supName
 newWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name
 Windows(thisWB).Activate
 Sheets("Sheet1").Select
 Range("A1:G1").Copy
 Windows(newWB).Activate
 Sheets("Sheet1").Select
 ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
 ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Paste
 Windows(thisWB).Activate
 Sheets("Sheet1").Select
 Range(Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, "A"), Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, "G")).Copy
 Windows(newWB).Activate
 Sheets("Sheet1").Select
 Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlValues
 Next i
 On Error GoTo 0
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

I am a VBA noob so any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In the original code, you have

```
Dim WS As Worksheet, newWS As Worksheet
Dim X As String
```

Dim WS as Worksheet and newWS as Worksheet tells Excel "WS and newWS will be worksheets."
Later in the code, these are set respectively, WS as Sheet1 in the active workbook, and newWS as a new worksheet within the active workbook.

Changing

```
Dim thisWB  As String
Dim newWB As String
```

to

```
Dim thisWB  As Workbook
Dim newWB As Workbook
```

should fix your issue.
You should be dimming thisWB and newWB as Workbooks, not strings.
Excel will be looking for a string of text instead of Workbooks.

Also - try looking on ExcelForum.com VBA section; I learnt a lot of what I know from there.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Aaron - but unfortunately my new workbooks are still empty. The step "thisWB = Activeworkbook.Name" seems not to work, so it never copies the cells from the original workbook. Any ideas?